# Генерация уникальных массивов из элементов одного родителя.

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, php

Здравствуйте.

Частично продвинулся в решении собственной задачи.
Теперь есть смысл перефразировать вопрос:

есть массив из трех элементов: `$arr = array("a","b","c")`

как возможно генерировать из него уникальные дочерние массивы с двумя элементами в каждом?

для заданного примера это:

```
$arr_1 = array("a", "b");
$arr_2 = array("a", "c");
$arr_3 = array("b", "c");
```

**а также**

как возможно сортировать массив с тремя элементами достигая всех шести возможных последовательностей элементов?

для заданного примера это:

```
$arr_1 = array("a","b","c"); *
$arr_2 = array("a","c","b");
$arr_3 = array("b","a","c");
$arr_4 = array("b","c","a");
$arr_5 = array("c","a","b");
$arr_6 = array("c","b","a"); *
```

*получить исходный и обратный ему массивы трудностей не составляет. вопрос в остальных четырех вариантах.

Может кто-то сможет предложить в какую сторону копать?

Нет необходимости писать листинг, мне лишь нужна помощь в составлении алгоритма.

Comment: Вариант про двойные массивы решен. 
Вопрос в сортировке тройного массива.

Comment: Всем спасибо, вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могу предложить решение для массива с тремя элементами:

```
$arr = array(
    'a',
    'b',
    'c'
);

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++)
    echo ($arr[$i] . ", ");
for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $c_arr = $arr;
    array_splice($c_arr, $i, 1);
    for ($j = 0; $j < 2; $j++)
        echo ($arr[$i] . $c_arr[$j] . ", ");
}

for ($i = 0; $i < 3; $i++) {
    $c_arr = $arr;
    array_splice($c_arr, $i, 1);
    echo ($arr[$i] . $c_arr[0] . $c_arr[1] . ",");
    echo ($arr[$i] . $c_arr[1] . $c_arr[0] . ",");
}
```

---

На самом деле все оказалось не так сложно. Например, мой метод заключается в простой перестановке элементов без модификации исходного массива.

Comment: то, что надо.

Comment: Это хорошо =)

Answer (score 1):

Твой вариант.

```
 $arr_1 = array("a", "b");
    $arr_2 = array("a", "c");
    $arr_3 = array("b", "c");
```

Вариант мой.

```
$arr[0] = array("a", "a");
$arr[0] = array("a", "b");
$arr[0] = array("a", "c");
$arr[0] = array("b", "a");
$arr[0] = array("b", "b");
$arr[0] = array("b", "c");
$arr[0] = array("c", "a");
$arr[0] = array("c", "b");
$arr[0] = array("c", "c");
```

Можно еще и так

Смысл просто в этом какой?

Обычно делают как. Берут массив значений. Делают из него другой массив всех элементов, допустим длиной 4 символа.

Т.е.

```
$arr = array("a", "b","c","d","e","r" и т.д.);
```

4 цикла for вложенных чтобы сделать массив.
пример.

```
a
b
c
d
.
.
.
.
.
aaaa
aaab
aaac
aaad
.
.
.
.
zzzy
zzzz
и т.д.
```

У тебя будет массив со всеми возможными значениями.

Вопрос у тебя такой

> Генерация уникальных строк из
> элементов одного массива.

Так зачем делать кучу массивов?  сделай один и с ним потом что душе угодно.

Comment: я, к сожалению, при редактировании случайно убрал из вопроса строчку о том, что генерированные строки не должны содержать в себе повторяющихся элементов.

т.е. ("a","a") не прокатит =(

Но за труд спасибо.

Comment: Прописать условие на то чтобы в строке не повторялись символы не так сложно.

Comment: @Shrek по поводу "почему куча массивов?"

после генерации, массивы переводятся в строки с несколькими разными разделительными символами между элементами, что уже реализовано функцией, которой нужно кормить массив.

Comment: А что мешает в цикле сделать массив из строк? Реализация такая же.